# Sending a list using RedirectToAction in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am having the following code

```
        public ActionResult Item_Post()
    {
        List<Product> products=new List<Product>() ;
        int? total=0;
       HttpCookie cookie= Request.Cookies["myvalue"];
       if (Request.Cookies["myvalue"] != null)
       {
           int count = Request.Cookies["myvalue"].Values.Count;
               var s = Request.Cookies["myvalue"].Value;
               s = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(s ?? string.Empty);
               string[] values = s.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();                      
               for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
               {
                   int id = Convert.ToInt32(values[i]);
                   Product product = db.Products.Single(x => x.Id == id);                       
                   total+=product.Price;
                   products.Add(product);
               }
               ViewBag.total = total;     
           TempData["products"]=products;   
       }
       Session["prod"] = products;
       return View("Buy", products);
       //return RedirectToAction("Buy");
    }
```

Now when I use only return View("Buy", products) I am getting the output  and the Url remains same as I want to change the Url and  when I use

```
return RedirectToAction("Buy", products);
```

I am getting error as I want to post the form to Buy. Are the parameters passed within the RedirectToAction appropriate or does it require anything else.
Here is the Action

```
@model IEnumerable<Shop_Online.com.Models.Product>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Buy";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div style="width: 860px; margin: 0 auto" class="main">
    <table border="1" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 13px">
        <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2">
            <th colspan="4">ITEM</th>
            <th>DELIEVERY DETAILS</th>
            <th>QTY</th>
            <th>SUB TOTAL</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" style="width: 46%">
                    <table style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 13px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="@Url.Content(item.Photo)" alt="Image" style="width:36px" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Model_Name)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color: #ccc">30 days Replacement</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 39%">Free Delievery Delivered in 2-3 business days.</td>
                <td style="width: 5%">1</td>
                <td style="width: 50%"><b>Rs. @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Price)</b></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 70px; background-color: #f2f2f2">
        <div style="width: 75%; height: 70px; float: left; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 13px">
        </div>
        <div style="width: 25%; height: 70px; float: left; font-family: Verdana; padding-top: 20px; font-size: 13px">
            Estimated Price: <b>Rs.@ViewBag.total</b>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="order" style="width: 100%; height: 70px">
        <div class="left-order" style="width: 75%; height: 70px; float: left"></div>
        <div class="left-order" style="width: 25%; float: left; height: 70px">
            <input type="button" value="PLACE ORDER" style="border: 1px solid #ec6723; width: 216px; cursor: pointer; height: 45px; color: #fff; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f77219 1%,#fec6a7 3%,#f77219 7%,#f75b16 100%)" onclick="return confirm('Successfull placed order')" />
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
}
```

And now how should I replace the below code within my View If I use TempData

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
 @Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.Name
 /some more code/
}
```

Comment: plz comment if anything is unclear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter

Comment: @ssilas777 it doesn't work as I am passing a list of values

Comment: Can you post your action `Buy`.

Comment: @karthik plz check the code

Comment: @karthik can u please tell me how to display it using a view

Comment: @User check the foreach usage in this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/18603441/1551730

Comment: @karthik My list contains 10 elements. Now let me become more specific. Plz check the edited post above

Comment: @karthik Thx for that I just had to return it within action method and that was where I made a mistake. Thx for your answer.

Comment: I have no problem but don't you think that I have answered first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get the `list` or any `model` objects passed to `RedirectToAction` in your action method. Because a `RedirectToAction` causes `HTTP 302 (Redirect)` request, which makes the browser to call **GET** request to the action.

You should use `TempData` to preserve the data in `Item_Post` action method.

```
public ActionResult Item_Post()
    {
        List<Product> products=new List<Product>() ;
        int? total=0;
       HttpCookie cookie= Request.Cookies["myvalue"];
       if (Request.Cookies["myvalue"] != null)
       {        
        some logic here
       }  
       //save it to TempData for later usage
       TempData["products"] = products;

       //return View("Buy", products);
       //return RedirectToAction("Buy", new {id=products});

       return RedirectToAction("Buy");
    }
```

And now in the `Buy` action use `TempData` to get your data.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Buy()
{
    var products = TempData["products"];
    //.. do anything
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

**UPDATE**

use the following code for `Buy` action.

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Buy()
        {
            var products = TempData["products"] as List<Product>;
            return View(products);
        }
```

And now in the view, use `foreach` over the list of elements in the products

```
@model IEnumerable<Shop_Online.com.Models.Product>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        Item Id: @item.Id
    </div>
    <div>
        Item name: @item.Name
    </div>
}
```

Now this should display you the list of all the items.

Or instead of assigning the `TempData` to an object of model class you can also try the following code which is the replacement for the above foreach.

```
@if (TempData["products"] != null)
{
    foreach (var item in TempData["products"] as List<Product>)
    {
        <div>
            Item Id: @item.Id
        </div>
        <div>
            Item name: @item.Name
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: @User Have you tried ? How many elements does your list contains ?

Comment: Temp data is not the way to go.

Comment: @KolobCanyon, what would be the better option, and why not TempData?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass array of products as id from RedirctToAction.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

It accept RouteParamter or just value that you pass in query string of url.

If you want to use RedirectToAction then I suggest that you should use TempData.

```
public ActionResult Item_Post()
    {
        List<Product> products=new List<Product>() ;
        int? total=0;
       HttpCookie cookie= Request.Cookies["myvalue"];
       if (Request.Cookies["myvalue"] != null)
       {        
        some logic here
       }                   
       TempData["Products"] = products;
       return RedirectToAction("Buy");
    }
```

In your Buy Action

```
 public ActionResult Buy()
{
   // Get value from TempData
   var products=  (List<Product>)TempData["Products"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your Buy ActionResult accept a `List<Product>` as a parameter, something like:

```
public ActionResult Buy(List<Product> ids)
{
    ...
}
```

Without this it will not know what to do with the list of products

Comment: exactly it is same as above mentioned by you. It works fine when I use return View("Buy", products). But the problem is the url remains the same. I want the url to be as http://localhost:16916/Home/Buy

Comment: RedirectToAction will grab the GET method, do you need to POST to /Home/Buy?

Comment: I want to move to /Home/Buy?